# Cannot remove PowerShell environment variables

Tags: powershell

I set two environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in Windows PowerShell before. Now I want to remove them but I find that no matter how I type the command, the next time I open PowerShell, these two variables will appear again.

Here are the commands I have tried:

```
$env:HTTP_PROXY=''
$env:HTTPS_PROXY=''

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTP_PROXY', '', 'User')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTPS_PROXY', '', 'User')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTP_PROXY', '', 'Machine')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTPS_PROXY', '', 'Machine')

Set-Location Env:
rm HTTP_PROXY
rm HTTPS_PROXY
```

But none of them works.

Comment: How were these set? Were these variable set in the Windows user and/or system environment variable sets with SETX or the GUI "Environment Variables" dialog box?

Comment: Try swapping `''`, to `$null`: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTPS_PROXY', $null, 'User')` instead.

Comment: @Abraham, `$null` is effectively passed as `''` by PowerShell, because the method parameter is `[string]`-typed. To pass an actual `null`, you'd have to use the `[NullString]::Value` singleton, which was specifically introduced for these scenarios. However, the `.SetEnvironmentVariable` method accepts the empty string, true `null`, and a string containing a single `NUL` (`0x0`) character interchangeably as a request to delete the variable.

Comment: @mklement, thank you! Good to know. Through where is `.SetEnvironmentVariable` exposed?

Comment: @Abraham, see the link labeled "By design" in my answer; it's a static method of the `[System.Environment]` class.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue here, note that (for the current session only) there's no need to enter the `Env:` virtual disk if you want to unset the env var, you can also simply provide the full path `rm env:myenvvar` in order to stay in the CWD if you want to. (And `$env:myenvvar = ''` is an equivalent, it actually unsets the variable too.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `$env:HTTP_PROXY=''`
> `$env:HTTPS_PROXY=''`
> Alternatively:
> `Set-Location Env:`
> `rm HTTP_PROXY`
> `rm HTTPS_PROXY`

The **statements above remove the specified environment variables *from the current session (process) only*** (note that on *Unix*-like platforms you'd have to use alias `ri` instead of `rm`, or use the cmdlet's full name, [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item), instead; e.g., without using `Set-Location` first, `ri Env:HTTP_PROXY`).

See also: [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables).

However, if these environment variables are defined *persistently*, via *the registry* (on Windows), they *will* resurface in future sessions.

---

> `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTP_PROXY', '', 'User')`
> `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTPS_PROXY', '', 'User')`
> `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTP_PROXY', '', 'Machine')`
> `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('HTTPS_PROXY', '', 'Machine')`

The **statements above** - assuming they execute without triggering an *exception* - ***do* remove the *persistent* definitions (on Windows only)**.

- Note that setting / removing *machine*-level variables (`'Machine'`) requires *elevation* (running as admin).
- [By design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable), any of the following values causes the specified environment variable to be *deleted*: `''`, `[NullString]::Value` (the equivalent of `null` in C#<sup>[1]</sup>), `` "`0" `` (a single `NUL` (`0x0`) char.)

  - As an aside: This permissiveness is problematic, as it prevents creating environment variables whose value is the *empty string*, which is not uncommon on Unix-like platforms - see [GitHub issue #50554](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50554).
- Note that these methods remove  *only* the *persistent definitions* of these variables - any definitions in the *current* session (process) are left untouched; to *also* remove them, use the methods at the top.

**If the environment variables unexpectedly still resurface in future sessions**, there are two **potential causes**:

- Perhaps you started a new session *directly from the old session*, e.g. with `Start-Process powershell.exe` - in that case the current session's environment variables are *inherited* by the new session, so unless you've removed the environment variable from the current session *as well*, the new session will see them.
- There may be code in your [*profile* files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), notably `$PROFILE`, that (re)defines these environment variables whenever a new session starts.

  - To rule out this possibility, use the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>) and submit `powershell -noprofile`, then check if these variables are still present.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell does have a `$null` constant that is *generally* the equivalent of C#'s `null`, but in a *string* context PowerShell forces `$null` values to `''` (the empty string). Therefore, the `[NullString]::Value` singleton is required in order to pass a genuine `null` value to a `string`-typed .NET method.</sup>